# How to sum row values until next blank cell?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-office

I need a formula to calculate the sum of values ​​in another **row**. To calculate the sum of the values ​​between two empty cells the result should be only one for each "flight".

[image: what it should look like]

Answer (score 0):

Put this in C2 and drag/copy across.

```
=IF(AND(B1="",C1<>""),SUM(C1:$M$1)-SUM(D2:$M$2),"")
```

It simply sums the numbers above and to the right and subtracts the values to the right(the ones already accounted for)

Note: it will not show the correct answer till it is copied/drug across the row.

[image]

Comment: I have another question, how is it possible that the values ​​are automatically combined for each flight, if the cells I want to combine contain formulas? For that example?